# access a dom element of a different page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

How do we access a DOM element of a different pages in javascript, let's say we have `page1.html` and `page2.html` and we would like to access an element of the `page2.html` once we click on a button on the `page1.html`. In vanilla Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm sure there are dozens of previous versions of this question with answers, but they're proving surprisingly hard to search for...*

You can't, unless

1. You have a reference to the other window containing the other page,

   and
2. The two pages are from the same domain (or [close enough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain)).

So in the normal case, you can't do it, because you don't have either of those things.

There are several ways a window can get a reference to another window's document:

- If `page1.html` opened `page2.html` via [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), `open` returns a reference to the new window.
- If `page1.html` contains `page2.html` as an iframe, it can get a reference to the window object for that iframe using the `contentWindow`  property of the `iframe` element in `page1.html`. (Or, in this case, get the document directly via [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) — provided #2 above is satisified.)
- If `page1.html` was opened by `page2.html`, it has access to `page2.html`'s window via the [`opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) global.
- If `page1.html` is an iframe within `page2.html`, it has access to `page2.html`'s window via the [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) global.
- If `page2.html` was opened such that the window it's in was given a *name* (for instance, `window.open(someURL, "example")`), a subsequent call to `window.open("", "example")` will return a reference to the existing window (at least if it's in the same origin; there may be restrictions).

Again, though, having a reference to the other window is only half the story (#1), #2 still applies.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to get deep into that.